# Laravel eager loading return if condition is true

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need some help to return a relation when condition is true

```php
$quizGroups = $quiz->groups()->with(['questionsBank' => function ($query) {
    return $query->with(['questions' => function ($query) {
        //if question->type === 'choices' return $query->with('choices')
    }]);
}])->get();
```

if condition is false just finish the other relations without getting choices

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I would just return `$query` if your test is false, and `$query->with('whatever')` if your test is true.

Edit: In fact, I don't even believe you need to actually return the query in these instances, so you can just do

```
if($the_test) {
    $query->with('whatever');
}
```

Comment: the condition is based on the Question instance if it's type is choice or not !